# VirtualBox to share clipboard and files

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, clipboard

I use `VirtualBox 5.2.6` on `Windows 10`. There is an `Ubuntu` virtual machine, from which I would like to access to host's clipboard and files.
I tried to use

> Machine>Settings >> General>Advanced>Shared Clipboard

I also tried

> Devices>Shared Clipboard>Bidirectional

I installed `virtualbox-guest-dkms` too, but has no effect.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the VM?

Comment: @iTechieGamer : Yes, sure, but doesn't helped in this problem.